# How to iterate through array and get row elements for each row in array - Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I need help assigning row elements in an array to a new variable using a for loop. 
e.g.

```
y = magic(2)

for i = size(y,1)
    m = y(i,:)
    % do some calculations to row vector 'm' and then iterate to next row vector and      replace previous 'm' with new 'm' and perform same calculations
end
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I'm basically writing out a k-means algorithm and i want to iterate through each of my data points, perform calculations on them and assign them to a cluster. I've managed to do all that correctly but for some reason it only performs it for the last row vector in my data...therefore skipping over all the others.

Comment: Then your problem is what I posted in my reply.

Answer (score 2):

It looks that your problem is the for loop, you are missing the initial value for the iterator `i`:

```
y = magic(2)
for i = 1:size(y,1)
    m = y(i,:)
    % use m
end
```

Comment: oh my goodness...i don't know how I missed it! I actually feel like an idiot...a rookie mistake. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

A little more direct: [`for`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) automatically iterates along *columns* of a matrix; so you can use:

```
y = magic(2);
for row = y.' %'// transpose y, and iterate through the columns of that
    %// 'row' contains each row of y, but as a column vector. Transpose if needed
end
```